# SQL - Replace multiple different characters with a single character within a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I want to clean up a string and replace various characters with an underscore_ within MS SQL.

The following code can achieve this :

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @new_string nvarchar(MAX)
SET @string = 'This is.my string/That Needs=cleaning'

SET @new_string = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string, ' ', '_'), '.', '_'), '/', '_'), '=', '_')

SELECT @new_string
```

This will then return 'This_is_my_string_That_Needs_cleaning'

I will use this to clean up filenames.

Is there a more efficient method, maybe via regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2017+ now supports [`translate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select @new_string = translate(@string, ' ./=', '____')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3af3a6213538eb07c8130a1ce9ab71eb) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful.  I am currently using SQL Server 2014 (pushing to upgrade soon so will save this solution).  I assume this also means there is no efficient method (other than building a function that replicates the above) in versions below 2017 ?

Comment: @Sharky99x . . . In older versions, the nested `replaces()` are probably the best solution.